# Problema al crear un pdf con php, html, y dompdf

Tags: php, html, dompdf

El pdf se crea pero me dice que esta dañado o no es un tipo de archivo admitido.
creo la consulta y la muesto en otra pagina con la linea echo $html , y se muetra bien, el problema surge cuando intento crear el pdf con Dompdf

```
<?php
    require_once("dompdf2/autoload.inc.php");
    use Dompdf\dompdf;
    require_once('includes/load.php');
    //page_require_level(1);
    $conn=new Conexion();
    $link = $conn->conectarse();
    //require_once("includes/conexion.php");
    //$departamentos =$_GET['departamentos'];
    //$rst_inventario=mysqli_query("SELECT t1.name as name1 ,t1.quantity,t1.marca,t1.serial,t1.model,t1.bien,t1.date, t2.name FROM
    products t1 INNER JOIN categories t2 ON t1.categorie_id=t2.id WHERE 
    t2.name =$departamentos", $link);
    $query="SELECT t1.name as name1 ,t1.quantity,t1.marca,t1.serial,t1.model,t1.bien,t1.date, t2.name FROM
    products t1 INNER JOIN categories t2 ON t1.categorie_id=t2.id WHERE 
    t2.name = '". $_GET["departamentos"] ."' order by categorie_id desc";
    $rst_inventario=mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    $html='
    <html>
    <body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h2 align="center" ><strong><u>LISTADO DE INVENTARIO POR DEPARTAMENTO</u></strong></h2>
    <table width="720" border="1" align="center">  
          <tr class="titulo2">
            <td style="text-align: center"><strong>Fecha de Ingreso</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align: center"><strong>Descripción</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align: center"><strong>Marca</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align: center"><strong>Modelo</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align: center"><strong>Nro. Serial</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align: center"><strong>Nro. Bienes Nacionales</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align: center"><strong>Departamento</strong></td>
            <td style="text-align: center"><strong>Stock</strong></td>
          </tr>';
          foreach ($rst_inventario as $result):
          $html.='
            <tr>  
              <td style="text-align: center">'.remove_junk($result['name1']).'</td>
              <td style="text-align: center">'.remove_junk($result['quantity']).'</td>
              <td style="text-align: center">'.remove_junk($result['marca']).'</td> 
              <td style="text-align: center">'.remove_junk($result['serial']).'</td>
              <td style="text-align: center">'.remove_junk($result['model']).'</td>
              <td style="text-align: center">'.remove_junk($result['bien']).'</td>
              <td style="text-align: center">'.remove_junk($result['date']).'</td>
              <td style="text-align: center">'.remove_junk($result['name']).'</td>
            </tr>';
            endforeach;;
        $html.='
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>';
        $h.='<h1>ddd</h1>';
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $dompdf->set_paper("A4", "landscape"); 
        $dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($h));
        // Creamos una instancia a la clase
        //echo $html; exit;
        $dompdf->render();
        //$pdf = $dompdf->output();
        $dompdf->stream('ReporteDepartamento.pdf');
        //exit();
        //
        ?
```

Este segundo cuadro de docigo estoy realizando una prueva simple con un h1, y se me crea el pdf sin problemas:

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf/autoload.inc.php");
use Dompdf\dompdf;
$h='<h1>ddd</h1>';
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_paper("A4", "landscape"); 
$dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($h));
// Creamos una instancia a la clase
//echo $html; exit;
$dompdf->render();
//$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$dompdf->stream('ReporteDepartamento.pdf');
exit();
?>
```

El problema surge cuando lo modifico y pongo todo lo demas de la consulta almacenada, y el html a mostrar como aparece en el primer codigo.

cada ves que introduzco dodico adicional del que se ve el ultimo cuadro me da erro al abrirlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `mysqli_query` retona un objeto  mysqli_result no un array, debes hacer uso de `mysqli_fetch_array` por ejemplo para trabajar los resultados como un array: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: cuando activo la linea de codigo echo $html; exit; para que me muestre la informacion recolectada el me lo muestra de forma correcta asi que no creo que sea el sql, el problema es al mandar a crear el archivo pdf con lo almacenado en $html

Comment: Estaria bien que edites la pregunta y que pongas el codigo tal cual lo tienes, por que parece que no lo copiaste bien y hay algunas lineas comentadas a medias y no esta muy claro de donde puede venir el problema. Por otro lado, te arroja algun error?

Comment: reformulo, creo la consulta y la muesto en otra pagina hasta hay todo bien el problema surge cuando intento crear el pdf , en el segundo cuadro de docigo estoy realizando una prueva simple con un h1, y se me crea el pdf sin problemas, pero cuando incorporo la consulta del primer codigo que ya proble y estaba funcionando se crea el pdf pero al abrirlo dice que esta dañado o no es un tipo de archivo acmitido